# Cytoscape.js - lock junction between node and edge

Tags: javascript, locking, cytoscape.js

I've a question about locking junctions between node and edges.
I don't want to lock node or fixed edges but just lock the point where the edges touch the node...
Does it possible ?
Perhaps I need to modify the cytoscape.js code... Can you help me to focus on the right section of it ?

Hope it make sense ?
Thanks a lot

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No.  Edges point toward node positions (i.e. centre).  Haystack edges have a specifiable distance/radius from those positions.  Probably the simplest implementation for what you're looking for would use an additional style property (e.g. 'haystack-angle') so you can effectively "lock" the edge endpoint position with a (haystack-radius, haystack-angle) pair.  If you're interested in adding that, you can make a pull request on the unstable branch.  Or you can make a ticket in the Github tracker.